# Read phone state runtime error in Android M

Tags: android, user-permissions

I have given the permission of read phone state in manifest as well as in activity . But still i am facing the runtime exception.
On the fragment , i had used telephony manger to get IMEI and on the activity i had given the runtime permission.

Here is my error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: getImei: Neither user 10122 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.
                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.telephony.IPhoneSubInfo$Stub$Proxy.getImeiForSubscriber(IPhoneSubInfo.java:532)
                                                                            at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getImei(TelephonyManager.java:783)
                                                                            at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getDeviceId(TelephonyManager.java:722)
                                                                            at com.sixmod.HomeFragment.sendTokenToServer(HomeFragment.java:3045)
                                                                            at com.sixmod.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:343)
```

The Code for the Activity is here :

```
private  boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
        int permissionSendMessage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        int locationPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
        if (permissionSendMessage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        }
        if (locationPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }

        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

In the onRequest permission i have checked like this :

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Permission callback called-------");
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {

                Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<>();
                // Initialize the map with both permissions
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                // Fill with actual results from user
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                        perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
                    // Check for both permissions
                    if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && perms.get(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "sms & location services permission granted");
                        // process the normal flow
                        //else any one or both the permissions are not granted
                    } else {
                        Log.d("TAG", "Some permissions are not granted ask again ");
                        //permission is denied (this is the first time, when "never ask again" is not checked) so ask again explaining the usage of permission
//                        // shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale will return true
                        //show the dialog or snackbar saying its necessary and try again otherwise proceed with setup.
                        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                            showDialogOK("Read Phone State and Location Services Permission required for this app",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            switch (which) {
                                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                                    checkAndRequestPermissions();
                                                    break;
                                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                                    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                                                    System.exit(1);
                                                    // proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                        //permission is denied (and never ask again is  checked)
                        //shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale will return false
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Go to settings and enable permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                            //                            //proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void showDialogOK(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", okListener)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
```

Comment: have you put permission in menifest?

Comment: YES , above application tag <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

Comment: try to clean and rebuild project

Answer (score 8):

add in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Request permission.

```
 int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);

        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
        } else {
            //TODO
        }
```

Handle callback when you request permission.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE:
            if ((grantResults.length > 0) && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                //TODO
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

For some permissions, you have to explicitly ask user in the runtime: 
http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this ,

mContext is your activity context

```
          private static final int REQUEST = 112;


          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION };
            if (!hasPermissions(mContext, PERMISSIONS)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST );
            } else {
                 //Do here
            }
        } else {
             //Do here
        }
```

get Permissions Result

```
        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            switch (requestCode) {
                case REQUEST: {
                    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                      //Do here
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "The app was not allowed to write to your storage.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

check permissions  for marshmallow

```
        private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
                for (String permission : permissions) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

AndroidManifest.xml file

```
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: @Barnali Bhattacharjee Change  Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
  To  android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION in your code

Comment: can you tell me in your above code ,if i have to give one more permission how i can do it , another one is FINE LOCATION permission

Comment: Check updated String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION };

Comment: again showing Neither user 10124 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.